# Maximizing number of consecutive days with the same operation mode for a scheduling problem

Tags: mathematical-optimization, job-scheduling, gams-math

I am solving a refinery scheduling problem in which process units can operate in different operation modes. Let's say a process unit X have two operation modes A and **B**. I am looking for an effective formulation that force my MILP scheduling model to produce a schedule for 10 days like AAAAAA**BBBB** instead of A**B**A**B**AA**B**A**B**A, i.e. number of mode switches should be minimal.

Currently in my model I have a binary variable *use_caps(mode, day)* that is 1 then an operation mode is selected for a day. I use this variable to construct the following 1-0 variable: *same_mode(mode, day) =e= use_caps(mode, day) +  use_caps(mode, day+1) - 1*. I compute it for all days except the final one.  As you see, the variable *same_mode(mode, day)* takes a value 1 then *day* and *day+1* use the same operation mode, otherwise it is 0.

Then I use it to *reward* the model for constructing a schedule with minimal switches. I do it by adding to my objective a bonus: *same_mode_bonus =e= sum((mode, days), same_mode(mode, day) * bonus_value)* where *bonus_value* is a relatively large parameter. As a have a profit maximization problem, my model tries to produce a required schedule. My strategy works well for many instances, but sometimes it fails. So my question is the following: is there other better strategy/formulation to construct such schedule or the only way to get better schedule is a tuning value of the parameter *bonus_value*?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your approach is correct:

```
 same_mode(mode, day) =e= use_caps(mode, day) + use_caps(mode, day+1) - 1
```

This will forbid for a given day:

```
 use_caps(mode, day) = use_caps(mode, day+1) = 0
```

as this would give `same_mode(mode, day) = -1`.

I probably would implement this as something along the lines of:

```
minimize sum(day, switch(day))
switch(day) >= use_caps(mode, day+1)-use_caps(mode, day)   ∀mode
switch(day) ∈ {0,1}
```

I.e. we count the times when we go from 0 to 1 (for one of the modes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the post in your blog. The model works much better. I forgot to mention that a process unit can use two modes inside a day to switch from one mode to another. To minimize such switches I added aditional constraints to calculate them. They are formulated also as 1-0 variable: shiftday(mode) =g= sum(mode, use_caps(mode, day)) -1